# What should be in box 4?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

The first box includes four months, and these are June, September, April and November.

The second box only includes March.

The third box contains May, August, July, December and January.

What should be in box 4, and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> October

Because the months given are

> increasing in length.

**Box 1:**

> April, June, September and November last 30 days

**Box 2:**

> March lasts 31 days minus 1 hour because of time change

**Box 3:**

> January, May, July, August, December last 31 days

**Box 4:**

> October lasts 31 days plus 1 hour because of time change

Comment: “What?? That can’t possibly… *oh.*”

Comment: But your reasoning for Box 2 only happens in certain countries. Not in countries like India.

Comment: The reasoning also doesn't work in the southern hemisphere.